# scope.$watch only checks for new value for a single time

Tags: angularjs

I have a function inside a directive (in link attribite):

```
scope.$watch('pickerSettings', function(pickerSettings){
   scope.pickerSettings = pickerSettings;
});
```

It watches for changes for pickerSettings in another directive to change the current value. Currect directive is used to call a modal. However - the directive only checks for the changes before the modal is opened. If it was opened - the settings are being saved and closing modal and changing the values in other directive will not change the settings. (By the way - modal opening is handled in another service).

I have added the code to log the object properties when opening the modal

```
    scope.showGallery = function () {
        console.log(scope);
        MediaService.showImagePicker(scope);
    };
```

It only logs the data when called for the first time.

Comment: What is the type of value assigned to `pickerSettings`, is it a string for example?

Comment: @mindparse - an Object with settings

Comment: Try using `$watchCollection`instead of `$watch`.

Comment: @Aer0 seems like the problem is that I have a 3 level nested object. Maybe that is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're doing this:

```
scope.$watch('pickerSettings', function(pickerSettings){
   scope.pickerSettings = pickerSettings;
});
```

This is watching the scope variable `pickerSettings` and on the initial digest and/or whenever angular detects a change it is re-assigning the detected change back to the same scope variable. If the scope variable itself is never reassigned to a different value, this watch will never fire again (and thus fire only once).

I'm guessing you probably want to react on a change on one of the sub properties. This can be done by specifying it in the watch expression like this:

```
scope.$watch('pickerSettings.mySubProperty', function(newValue){
   /* handle magic here */
});
```

... or by using `$watchGroup` to watch an array of expressions:

```
scope.$watchGroup([
  'pickerSettings.prop1', 
  'pickerSettings.prop2'
], function(newValues){

   var prop1 = newValues[0], prop2 = newValues[1];

   /* handle magic here */

});
```

... or by using `$watchCollection` to watch (one level deep) sub-properties:

```
scope.$watchCollection('pickerSettings', function(newValue){

   /* handle magic here */

});
```

... or by using a custom watch function that is called every digest cycle:

```
function myCustomWatch() {

  // If the return value of this function differs from 
  // the last digest cycle the watch callback is triggered.

  if(scope.pickerSettings.items.length) {
    return scope.pickerSettings.items[0].someValue;
  }

  return -1;
}

scope.$watch(myCustomWatch, function(newValue){

   /* handle magic here */

});
```

Hope this helps.